# Get current URL/URI without some of $_GET variables

Tags: php, frameworks, uri, yii, current-page

How, in Yii, to get the current page's URL. For example:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/your_yii_application/?lg=pl&id=15
```

but excluding the `$GET_['lg']` (without parsing the string manually)?

I mean, I'm looking for something similar to the `Yii::app()->requestUrl` / `Chtml::link()` methods, for returning URLs minus some of the `$_GET` variables.

**Edit**: Current solution:

```
unset $_GET['lg'];

echo Yii::app()->createUrl(
  Yii::app()->controller->getId().'/'.Yii::app()->controller->getAction()->getId() , 
  $_GET 
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the querystring and get only the url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969645/how-to-remove-the-querystring-and-get-only-the-url)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413062/get-current-url-uri-without-some-of-get-variables

Answer (score 80):

### Yii 1

```
Yii::app()->request->url
```

### For Yii2:

```
Yii::$app->request->url
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since the asker want to be done with Yii

Comment: This is not what the poster asked for. See the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413062/yii-how-do-you-get-current-url-uri-without-some-of-get-variables/22460712#22460712

Comment: This is the wrong answer. User needs to EXCLUDE some GET parameters.

Comment: This anwer has a lot of up votes but it is misleading, @MichaelButler answer is very good but you can see shorter yii2 specific answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413062/get-current-url-uri-without-some-of-get-variables/33409343#33409343

Comment: Yii2: Yii::$app->request->url

Answer (score 32):

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(Yii::app()->request->url)
```

This will output something in the following format:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/your_yii_application/
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, sometimes the url includes not just controller and action, but view, and depends on the route methods.

Comment: I think this is wrong. Because `createAbsoluteUrl` expects a route not a URL. The author's original solution is quite right but a more correct one would be: `$this->createUrl($this->getRoute(), $_GET)` and before calling it, unset from `$_GET` the params that you don't wish.

Comment: **This is terrible answer, don't use it!** It will give you a bunch of bugs when your URLs does not match routes. For example if `/news/index` should display route `news/view` for `News` model with slug `index`. With this answer you will get incorrect URL - it will redirect you to URL for `/news/index` *route* instead  `/news/view`.

Answer (score 23):

### Yii 1

Most of the other answers are wrong. The poster is asking for the url WITHOUT (some) $_GET-parameters.

Here is a complete breakdown (creating url for the currently active controller, modules or not):

```
// without $_GET-parameters
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->action->id);

// with $_GET-parameters, HAVING ONLY supplied keys
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->action->id,
    array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip(['id']))); // include 'id'

// with all $_GET-parameters, EXCEPT supplied keys
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->action->id,
    array_diff_key($_GET, array_flip(['lg']))); // exclude 'lg'

// with ALL $_GET-parameters (as mensioned in other answers)
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->action->id, $_GET);
Yii::app()->request->url;
```

When you don't have the same active controller, you have to specify the full path like this:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('/controller/action');
Yii::app()->createUrl('/module/controller/action');
```

Check out the Yii guide for building url's in general: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls

Comment: Yes, great answer! (and indeed the only correct one to the question) Could use an update it for Yii2 too though..

Comment: found it: __Yii2__: ```Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(array_merge([Yii::$app->requestedRoute], $getParams));```

Answer (score 15):

To get the absolute current request url (exactly as seen in the address bar, with GET params and http://) I found that the following works well:

```
Yii::app()->request->hostInfo . Yii::app()->request->url
```

Answer (score 12):

In Yii2 you can do:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
$withoutLg = Url::current(['lg'=>null], true);
```

More info:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#current%28%29-detail

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about doing it in Yii, but you could just do this, and it should work anywhere (largely lifted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389195/what-server-variable-provide-full-url/8389271#8389271)):

```
// Get HTTP/HTTPS (the possible values for this vary from server to server)
$myUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && !in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']),array('off','no'))) ? 'https' : 'http';
// Get domain portion
$myUrl .= '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// Get path to script
$myUrl .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// Add path info, if any
if (!empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) $myUrl .= $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

$get = $_GET; // Create a copy of $_GET
unset($get['lg']); // Unset whatever you don't want
if (count($get)) { // Only add a query string if there's anything left
  $myUrl .= '?'.http_build_query($get);
}

echo $myUrl;
```

Alternatively, you could pass the result of one of the Yii methods into [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), and manipulate the result to re-build what you want.

Comment: This is really helpful. My only consideration is that Yii is using either the 'normal' (?var=value) format, or PATH (/var/value), they are toggled in a config file. That's why links in Yii are constructed using Chtml::link() with an array of $_GET variables.

Comment: Oh ! So I can... give the whole $_GET array as an input parameter, after unsetting one value :). [leaves for a minute to try it].

Comment: @Sebastian This could be easily re-worked to use it in `/var/value` format - the exact details of how it would be done depend on the situation, but in effect you are just reformatting strings from the input data, so it's not that difficult. You can just do something like `foreach ($get as $key => val) $myUrl .= "/$key/$val";` (may need slight alteration depending on exactly how your URLs are formatted).

Comment: elegant trick with the "/$key/$val"! Another solution: `Yii::app()->createUrl(Yii::app()->controller->getId().'/'.Yii::app()->controller->getAction()->getId(), $_GET );` seems to work (after unsetting `$_GET['lg']` :)!

Comment: No need to write code that Yii already provides. Read this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest

Answer (score 6):

You are definitely searching for this

```
Yii::app()->request->pathInfo
```

Comment: This one is the correct answer. But for yii2 it should be `Yii::$app->request->pathInfo`

Answer (score 5):

So, you may use

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)
```

to get an Absolute webroot url, and strip the http[s]://

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, if run in the controller:

```
$controller = $this;
$path = '/path/to/app/' 
  . $controller->module->getId() // only necessary if you're using modules
  . '/' . $controller->getId() 
  . '/' . $controller->getAction()->getId()
. '/';
```

This assumes that you are using 'friendly' URLs in your app config.

Comment: Relying on one particular url style is bad and unnessecary. See this topic about creating url's in general: yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls

Answer (score 1):

```
$validar= Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii2

```
Url::current([], true);
```

or

```
Url::current();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Yii2:
This should be safer `Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl` rather than `Yii::$app->request->url`

Answer (score 0):

**For Yii1**

I find it a clean way to first get the current route from the CUrlManager, and then use that route again to build the new url. This way you don't 'see' the baseUrl of the app, see the examples below.

Example with a controller/action:

```
GET /app/customer/index/?random=param
$route = Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request);
var_dump($route); // string 'customer/index' (length=14)
$new = Yii::app()->urlManager->createUrl($route, array('new' => 'param'));
var_dump($new); // string '/app/customer/index?new=param' (length=29)
```

Example with a module/controller/action:

```
GET /app/order/product/admin/?random=param
$route = Yii::app()->urlManager->parseUrl(Yii::app()->request);
var_dump($route); // string 'order/product/admin' (length=19)
$new = Yii::app()->urlManager->createUrl($route, array('new' => 'param'));
var_dump($new); string '/app/order/product/admin?new=param' (length=34)
```

This works only if your urls are covered perfectly by the rules of CUrlManager :)

Answer (score 0):

## For Yii2

I was rather surprised that the correct answer for Yii2 was in none of the responses.

The answer I use is:

```
Url::to(['']),
```

You can also use:

```
Url::to()
```

...but I think the first version makes it more obvious that your intention is to generate a url with the curent request route. (i.e. "/index.php?admin%2Findex" if you happened to be running from the actionIndex() in the AdminController.

You can get an absolute route with the schema and domain by passing true as a second parameter, so:

```
Url::to([''], true)
```

...would return something like "https://your.site.domain/index.php?admin%2Findex" instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this variant:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('your_yii_application/?lg=pl', array('id'=>$model->id));?>
```

It is the easiest way, I guess.

Comment: Hardcoding the url is a bad practise. See this topic about creating url's in general: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers are wrong.

The Question is to get url without some query param .

Here is the function that works. It does more things actually. You can remove the param that you don't want and you can add or modify an existing one.

```
/**
 * Function merges the query string values with the given array and returns the new URL
 * @param string $route
 * @param array $mergeQueryVars
 * @param array $removeQueryVars
 * @return string
 */
public static function getUpdatedUrl($route = '', $mergeQueryVars = [], $removeQueryVars = [])
{
    $currentParams = $request = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams();

    foreach($mergeQueryVars as $key=> $value)
    {
        $currentParams[$key] = $value;
    }

    foreach($removeQueryVars as $queryVar)
    {
        unset($currentParams[$queryVar]);
    }

    $currentParams[0] = $route == '' ? Yii::$app->controller->getRoute() : $route;

    return Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($currentParams);

}
```

usage:

```
ClassName:: getUpdatedUrl('',[],['remove_this1','remove_this2'])
```

This will remove query params 'remove_this1' and 'remove_this2' from URL and return you the new URL

Answer (score -1):

```
echo Yii::$app->request->url;
```

Comment: How does this remove "some" of the variables from the URL?